# Atmel Email Verification URL is broken

Tags: atmel, atmelstudio

Does someone have in email history the Atmel URL base path for Email-Address verification?

They send me a broken URL, just the part after "?". So I can not complete registration nor download plugins for Atmel Studio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By searching in the Internet I found on a page the missing URL part:

http://www.atmel.com/system/confirm.aspx

So you need to add the ?... part of the confirmation email behind.

Note: I think because of the wrong URL, some email providers block the confirm email also as spam. With gmail I was able to register.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still looking for answer of your query. Hosted url is changed now for atmel studio extensions. You can get the extensions from https://gallery.microchip.com/ , with this new extension hosting user does not require to login to download extensions. You need to register if you wish to upload some atmel studio extension.
Regards,
Ashok